# Asus Eee PC 900HA charger broke - laptop won't charge or turn on with other chargers

Tags: laptop, eee-pc, charger

I have an ASUS Eee PC 900HA laptop that was given to me - unfortunately the charger broke.

I replaced it with a charger for a HP Mini laptop that had the right size connector - initially it seemed to work but then turned off. When I tried to turn it back on, each time it would only turn on for a second and then turn off again. I tried a Targus universal charger which seemed to charge for a second, but then nothing - the light wasn't even turned on.

Any ideas how to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

In the rear of the charger there will be a set of numbers.

One of them will be the model number.  Google for this number and you should be able to find a supplier to buy a new power supply.

Alternatively, there are 3 things you need to know in order to use another power supply:

1. **The plug style.** This has to match exactly.  If you have to force it in then you will end up damaging your motherboard.
2. **The voltage.**  This has to match.  Using a power supply that provides too much voltage will blow up the computer.  Using one that doesn't provide enough will just plain not work.
3. **The amperage.**  The power supply has to provide *at least* as much current as the old power supply.  It doesn't matter if it can provide more - if anything that's a good thing.  If it can't provide enough then there is a chance that the computer will blow the power supply.

By just plugging any old power supply and hoping one of either 2 or 3 may already have happened.

Comment: its unlikely, but i'd add checking the polarity of the inner/outer connections to that.

Answer (score 0):

Take note of answer 2 above. Just because the plug fits does not mean it is the correct size - the internal hole could be a little big.

Two solutions:

1. Often when powered externally a laptop screen will be a little brighter. While the machine is on waggle the connector and fix it in the position that has the bright screen.
2. Buy an adaptor. In the UK, Maplin supply a number of these.